# JQuery autocomplete disable some results

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-autocomplete, disable-link

i have a jquery autocomplete with ajax in my view with this code:

```
$('#QuickSearchProduct').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        var url = url ? url : $(this.element).attr('data-autocomplete-url');
        cache[url] = cache[url] || {};
        if (term in cache[url]) {
            response(cache[url][term]);
            return;
        }
        var url = url ? url : $(this.element).attr('data-autocomplete-url');
        lastXhr = $.getJSON(url, request, function (data, status, xhr) {
            cache[url][term] = data;
            if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, result) {
        var callback_url = $(this).attr('data-callback-url');
        console.log('url', callback_url);
        var idContainer = result.item.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: callback_url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { idContainer: idContainer },
            success: function (container) {
                var newLine = BlankPriceListLine;
                newLine.Barcode = container.Barcode;
                newLine.IdContainer = container.IdContainer;
                newLine.ContainerName = container.ContainerName;
                newLine.SuggestedRP = container.SuggestedRP;
                newLine.IdCurrency = container.IdCurrency;
                newLine.IdTaxCode = container.IdTaxCode;
                console.log('newLine', newLine);
                vm.addLine(new MasterPriceListLines(newLine));
            }
        });    
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

In the code, the autocomplete is for a quick search of products and when the item is selected in the results, then that item is added to a list with the method vm.addLine, this is done with knockout js.
The thing is that i would like to disable the results that are already on the list, so.. how can i disable that result in the autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

You could try filtering the autcomplete results with data from your VM list.

```
response(ko.utils.arrayFilter(data, function(item) {
    return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.Lists, function(listItem) {
        return listItem.id === item.id;
    }
}
```

Something like that would filter your result list by excluding any item that already existed in the VM list, assuming you are comparing by id's' but the general idea is the same.

**Update**

if you want more customization of how the items look, you can overwrite the _renderItem function in jquery ui.  i took the autocomplete example from the jquery ui website and modified it to show an "existing" selection in a different way so users couldnt select it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3UDAk/6/

Comment: This is a really great aproach to what i whant, but the thing with this change is that the "select" event keeps firing if i use the arrow keys to navigate on the select and select the "disabled" item.